# No response from Adobe Document Generator API

Tags: post, azure-blob-storage, adobe, adobe-documentgeneration

I am trying to use the Document Generation API from Adobe, using a external storage (blob storage azure) I am following the guide, but am receiving no response when I post to the API

I am trying to use the Document Generation API from Adobe, which takes request body:

```json
{
  "input": {
    "uri": "",
    "storage": "BLOB"
  },
  "output": {
    "uri": "",
    "storage": "BLOB"
  },
  "params": {
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "jsonDataForMerge": {
      "customerName": "Kane Miller",
      "customerVisits": 100,
      "itemsBought": [
        {
          "name": "Sprays",
          "quantity": 50,
          "amount": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "Chemicals",
          "quantity": 100,
          "amount": 200
        }
      ],
      "totalAmount": 300,
      "previousBalance": 50,
      "lastThreeBillings": [
        100,
        200,
        300
      ],
      "photograph": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP88h8AAu0B9XNPCQQAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    }
  }
}
```

This is the example shown by Adobe, except I have changed the storage to Blob as I am using Azure. I have made 2 blob storage containers, one contains the template in word format, and the other a blank storage for output. For the request body input, I have generated a SAS Token and URL, and put the URL in the uri request for the input. For the Output, I have generated a SAS token of the empty container, and put the URL in the uri request. When I try to post this data, It doesn't return anything. Am I understanding the input and output of the request body wrong? why am I not getting any response from the API?

Comment: I have already added the correct Header params, of authorization and x-api-key

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: the problem is that there is not response from the POST, If i change the storage type to "sharepoint", instead of blob, it gives me error " storage type does not match" , but once everything is inputted in, it gives me no response.

Comment: This is the documentation, https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/apis/#tag/Document-Generation/operation/pdfoperations.documentgeneration , I am using external storage (azure), I am not too experienced with this stuff, but I think maybe there is a difference between "Signed URI" and what im inputting in, "SAS URL"?

Comment: When you say no response, what do you mean? I want to be clear - if you do it right,  you get a 201 status result and the location header is the Job url to check. So the response BODY is empty, not the headers.

Comment: When I try to input everything correctly, I literally get nothing in response. Like no response code no error nothing.

Comment: For the input, I am getting the SAS URL for the File I uploaded to the blob storage, for the output, I am getting the SAS URL for the container, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in the comments, the issue is that on a *successful* post to create a job, our API returns a Location header in the response that is the URL you can use to check the job status. It is expected that the body is empty as the relevant information is in the Location header.